# sourcing S4 class files

Tags: r

I have created multiple S4 classes (i.e., reference class) in a "classes" directory on my computer. I'm trying to source them all into my program. Here is what I do:

```
workingDirectory<-getwd()
myClasses<-dir(paste(workingDirectory,"/classes",sep=""))
   if (length(myClasses)!=0){
     sapply(1:length(myClasses),function(x) 
     source(paste(workingDirectory,"/classes/",myClasses[x],sep="")))
   }
```

I keep getting the following error:
Error in getClass(what, where = where) : “event” is not a defined class

This only happens to my classes. I do the same thing for bunch of function files I created and I'm able to source them all into my program.

Any suggestion what is happening here?!?!?

Comment: S4 methods need to be defined in a specific order.  With normal functions it typically doesn't cause an error to define them in any random order but you need to be more careful with the order you define things with S4.

Comment: so what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: The "proper" way would be to make a proper package and use the collate directive to specify the order that files need to be read.  Otherwise just make sure you read in your files in the correct order. I don't work with S4 much (read this as: ever) so can't give much more guidance.